# Why does this song use “find ich dich” instead “ich find dich”?

Tags: word-order, lyrics

The lyrics of a song by Helene Fischer are:

> Zwischen Gestern und Morgen da **find’ ich dich.**
>   Gib uns nicht verloren und suche mich.

Why does she use “find ich dich”, instead of “ich find dich”?

Comment: Little surprisingly, a short Internet search yielded that there is only one song by Helene Fischer containing “find ich dich”.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order

Comment: Or why not: "da Dich ich find" or "da ich Dich find" (Gib uns nicht verloren, Blumenkind) - for the rhyme. :)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft *Little surprisingly?* It’s coming as a big surprise to me, tbh.

Comment: @Jan: I do not know this singer, but the probability to find such a sequence of words twice in any singer’s repertoire is very low.

Comment: ich sehe hier http://www.songtexte.com/songtext/helene-fischer/zwischen-himmel-und-erde-bc25dc2.html ein Komma...

Answer (score 3):

Well, even though this question is inspired by Helene Fischer lyrics, here's my attempt to provide an answer:

*Ich finde dich* can be used alone (*I (will) find you*) or it can be used in conjunction with a closer definition about how, when or where you will be found (or how you are considered to be, because that's a second meaning of *Ich finde dich* => *I think you are...*). That's called the adverbial of time, manner, cause, etc.

For example:

> Ich finde dich im Garten (I (will) find you in the garden)
>   Ich finde dich, wenn die Sonne untergeht (I (will) find you when sun sets)
>   Ich finde dich süß (I think you're cute)

The positions of the main clause *Ich finde Dich* and the adverbial can be swapped. However, you then have to change the word order also if you don't want to sound like Yoda:

> Im Garten finde ich dich
>   Wenn die Sonne untergeht finde ich dich
>   Süß finde ich dich

The latter word order puts some emphasis on the attributes:

> *Im Garten* finde ich dich (not in the garage)
>   *Wenn die Sonne untergeht* finde ich dich (not at noon)
>   *Süß* finde ich dich (not ugly)

Comment: Please edit the OP, if you are sure the question is referring to these lyrics. The answer is very simple then: The verb stands at the second position in a german main clause, the other parts can be swapped.

Comment: »Find ich die Fundstelle, kann ich die Antwort vielleicht widerlegen« ;)

Comment: FYI: I took the liberty to find the actual lyrics this question is about. You may want to address this in your answer.

Comment: Ich denke das "da" spielt eine zu große Rolle, als dass man es in der Betrachtung unter den Tisch fallen lassen könnte. "Zwischen Gestern und Morgen, da find ich Dich" ok, aber wohin mit dem da bei  "Zwischen Gestern und Morgen, ich find Dich"?